# Different material to different letters in text with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, text-object

Is there a way in which I can change the material of different letters of a text frame by frame with animation nodes? Like, the capital letters in the example underneath would be of a different color than the rest:

frame 1    Text
frame 2    tExt
frame 3    teXt
frame 4    texT

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: No idea yet, but just for clarification: you want the capitalization to be the distinctive feature, or the letter itself?

Comment: The feature I'm looking for is a different color than the rest of the text object. So the word is visible throughout the animation, say in red letters, but successively each letter changes color once to blue. So in the above example, in frame 1 the first t is blue and the rest red, in frame 2 the e is blue and the rest red, and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you can get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Works like a charm

Comment: you are welcome